# Highcharts Error #18 in - Highcharts.Chart(options)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Given the follow [Highcharts.Chart(options)](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.Chart)

```
{
                "chart": {
                    "type": "spline"
                },
                "title": {
                    "text": "",
                    "x": -20
                },
                "subtitle": {
                    "text": "",
                    "x": -20
                },
                "xAxis": [
                    "23 Jun",
                    "24 Jun",
                    "25 Jun",
                    "26 Jun",
                    "27 Jun",
                    "28 Jun",
                    "29 Jun"
                ],
                "yAxis": {
                    "title": {
                        "text": ""
                    },
                    "plotLines": [
                        {
                            "value": 0,
                            "width": 1,
                            "color": "#808080"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "legend": {
                    "layout": "vertical",
                    "align": "right",
                    "verticalAlign": "middle",
                    "borderWidth": 0
                },
                "series": [
                    {
                        "name": "exposed",
                        "data": [
                            100,
                            200,
                            150,
                            130,
                            180,
                            200,
                            190
                        ],
                        "dashStyle": "longdash"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "converted",
                        "data": [
                            90,
                            80,
                            70,
                            75,
                            70,
                            80,
                            85
                        ],
                        "dashStyle": "longdash"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "engaged",
                        "data": [
                            30,
                            40,
                            35,
                            40,
                            48,
                            30,
                            33
                        ],
                        "dashStyle": "longdash"
                    }
                ]
            }
```

When I *draw* it with - `$('#container').highcharts({...})` it prompts the error -

```
Uncaught Highcharts error #18: www.highcharts.com/errors/18
```

http://www.highcharts.com/errors/18

You can see it in  - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/urielz/bcAF6/1/)

What is wrong with that `options` format ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a container in the jsFiddle

there is a problème with the x axis. You have to define an object not only an array. Ex

```
"xAxis": {categories: [
                    '23 Jun',
                    '24 Jun',
                    '25 Jun',
                    '26 Jun',
                    '27 Jun',
                    '28 Jun',
                    '29 Jun'
                          ]}
```

do you expect somethink like this http://jsfiddle.net/x4YbZ/ ?